# Rearrange only specific columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have several dataframes that all share common fields. Any other fields are specific to the dataframe. When output to Excel, the columns output in no particular order and I'd like them to have the shared columns display first in each dataframe.

```
aaa   bbb   ccc  col1   col2   col3
 1     2     3   Name   Date   Bank
```

Desired output:

```
col1   col2   col3  aaa   bbb   ccc
Name   Date   Bank   1     2     3
```

I can do this:

```
columns_i_want_first = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
df = df.reindex(columns=columns_i_want_first)
```

But obviously that drops the rest of the columns. Is there any way I can tack on something like `else df.columns.tolist()` in the reindexing? Or is there just a more general, elegant way of performing this type of reassignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something like:

```
columns_i_want_first = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
df=(pd.concat([df.reindex(columns_i_want_first,axis=1),
             df[df.columns.difference(columns_i_want_first)]],axis=1))

   col1  col2  col3  aaa  bbb  ccc
0  Name  Date  Bank    1    2    3
```

Or if the objective is object columns first and then int, use:

```
pd.concat([df.select_dtypes('object'),df.select_dtypes('int')],axis=1)
```